# Discover data aware controls linked to a dataset field

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, what should I do to get the list of data aware controls linked to a dataset field on any open form?

Thanks

Comment: Would be nice, but it's not trivial. A TDataSet has a list of DataSources linked to it, but it's only a private field. The DataSource, if you would be able to find it, has a list of TDataLink, but it's protected. TDataLink is doesn't link to a control; specific descendants of TDataLink _might_ expose 'their' component, for instance TFieldDataLink, the one used by TDBEdit and friends, exposes a public Control property of TComponent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is based on my answer to this q: [How to find out which DB-Aware controls are linked to a TDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361447/how-to-find-out-which-db-aware-controls-are-linked-to-a-tdatasource)
which asked how to find which db-aware controls are linked to a given datasource.

It uses the traditional RTTI found in TypInfo.Pas, so will work with virtually
any version of Delphi.  It does not require the more recent RTTI.Pas.  The example below is written and tested in D7.

As of now, this answer is not quite complete because

a) it only goes as far as listing which components in a container object
(e.g. a Form or DataModule) are linked in a db-aware fashion to a given dataset, but extending it
to find which controls are linked to a specific field of the dataset; and

b) it assumes that the db-aware controls follow the Delphi convention of having
a `DataSource` field and, if the control is one which operates on a specific field
of the dataset (e.g. a TDBEdit, but not e.g. a TDBGrid), a `DataField` one.

How the code works is explained in the inline comments; basically, it iterates the
components in the container looking for DataSources, then checks whether they are
linked to a given dataset, then looks for controls which specify the datasource
in their `DataSource` field, if any, and extracts the value of the `DataField`
property if the control is of a type which has one.  On obvious to-do item would
be to extend the code to cover the situation where the dataset and/or dataset
are in a different container (e.g. a DataModule) than the db-aware controls.

The sample project includes a TClientDataSet, TDataSource, TDBGrid and two
DBEdits wired up in the way you would expect and produces the output

```
    DataSource: DataSource1 DataSet: ClientDataSet1
    DBEdit1 (Classname: TDBEdit) is linked to ClientDataSet1
     on datafield: ID
    DBEdit2 (Classname: TDBEdit) is linked to ClientDataSet1
     on datafield: Name
```

so I hope it's fairly clear that it should be capable, with a bit more
work, of doing what you're asking for.  For now, I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Code

```
  uses ... typinfo;

  procedure TForm1.Log(Msg: String);
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Msg);
  end;

  function DataSourceHasDataSet(ADataSource : TDataSource; ADataSet : TDataSet) : Boolean;
  begin
    Result := ADataSource.DataSet = ADataSet;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FindControlsForDataSet(AContainer : TComponent; ADataSet : TDataSet);
  var
    i, j : Integer;
    ADataSource : TDataSource;
    AComponent,
    BComponent : TComponent;
    AObject : TObject;
    PInfo : PPropInfo;
    AFieldName : String;

  begin
    // iterate the container looking for datasources
    for i := 0 to AContainer.ComponentCount - 1 do begin
      AComponent := AContainer.Components[i];
      if AComponent is TDataSource then begin
        ADataSource := TDataSource(AComponent);
        //  Check that ADataSource is linked to our specifiied dataset
        if DataSourceHasDataSet(ADataSource, ADataSet) then begin
          Log('DataSource: ' + ADataSource.Name + ' DataSet: ' + ADataSet.Name);

          //  now, iterate the container looking for controls which
          //  have a DataSource property specifying the found datasource
          for j := 0 to AContainer.ComponentCount - 1 do begin
            BComponent := AContainer.Components[j];
            PInfo := GetPropInfo(BComponent, 'DataSource');
            //  PInfo will be non-NIL of the BComponent has a DataSource property
            if PInfo <> Nil then begin
              AObject := GetObjectProp(BComponent, PInfo);
              if (AObject <> Nil) then
                if (AObject is TDataSource) then begin
                  Log(BComponent.Name + ' (Classname: ' + BComponent.ClassName + ') is linked to ' + ADataSet.Name);
                  PInfo := GetPropInfo(BComponent, 'DataField');
                  if PInfo <> Nil then begin
                    AFieldName := GetStrProp(BComponent, 'DataField');
                    Log(' on datafield: ' + AFieldName);
                  end;
                end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.btnFindClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    FindControlsForDataSet(Self, ClientDataSet1);
  end;
```

As the items of interest may be spread across different forms/datamodules,
you can use the `Screen` object to list them

```
  procedure TForm1.btnFormsClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i : Integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to Screen.CustomFormCount - 1 do begin
      Log(Screen.CustomForms[i].Name);
    end;
    for i := 0 to Screen.DataModuleCount - 1 do begin
      Log(Screen.DataModules[i].Name);
    end;
  end;
```